# Why was q721019 closed?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons, reopen

If you know what Poiseuille's equation is then [Physiology question about velocity and radius](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/721019/2451) is perfectly clear and a straightforward answer solves the questioner's conceptual difficulty. Yet the question was closed with the tag "Needs details or clarity". Was this appropriate?

Comment: I disagree.  Maybe it’s the style (emoticons not withstanding ) or the syntax or the grammar but I find this question difficult to parse: there seems to be missing elements.  It could also very much benefit from editing.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Okay, I have edited the question to remove the emojis and improve the spelling and grammar.

Comment: I still think there are things missing, *v.g* “Why does this give a different result ?”. Different from what?  Also “these two formulae are related to each other.” but what two formulae? The OP inserted one into the other (AFAI can tell).

Comment: it’s now reopened.  I can’t vote to close it again but it still needs clarifications.